# How to have several screens in html and swipe these screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, html

Can anyone tell me how to have several screens in a HTML page and swipe these screens as a native Android applications does.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a mobile application only? Have you considered jQuery Mobile?

Comment: jQuery Mobile overrides my styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sencha touch framework for this.

Comment: But still it will provide you native look

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED ANSWER**

If you are thinking in a horizontal scrolling page, you can find some inspiration here:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/

or:
http://www.sitepoint.com/side-scrolling-site-layout-with-css-and-jquery/

or here:
http://www.thewebsqueeze.com/web-design-tutorials/create-a-horizontal-scrolling-website.html

**OLD ANSWER**

You could use a plugin like scrolldeck:

```
http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrolldeck.js/
```

Comment: I've tried scrolldeck but it doesn't work good on android. Try it on your side, any links from http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrolldeck.js/decks/responsive
http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrolldeck.js/decks/infographics
http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrolldeck.js/decks/parallax don't help.

Comment: @Sergey- it works with keystrokes (arrows) but I suppose it can be customized. Paralax works with the radio buttons on the right.

Comment: @Sergey: what was the solution you found?

Answer (score 0):

There a are some projects you can use to help you with this:

- [Jquery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)
- [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch)